# How to turn "on and off" of git submodule based on repo status

Tags: git

Let's say I have three repos, `child`, `parent` and `grandparent`. `parent` has a submodule `child`, and `grandparent` has two submodules `parent` and `child`.

What I want to achieve is that `parent` only checks out (or init and update) `child` when `parent` itself is a standalone repo (rather than a submodule of another repo). And when `parent` is a submodule of `grandparent`, it won't check out its own `child`, but will use the `child` provided by `grandparent`. The reason I am doing this is because `child` and `parent` are large stem repos, and `grandparent` is leaf. So there are many different `grandparent` repos, each with its submodule pointing to different commits in `child` and `parent`. And since `child` is large, I don't want to keep another copy of it in `parent`. To be more precise, `child` is an asset repo containing all kinds of data and assets. `parent` is parser to the data. And `grandparent` is application using the parser to access the assets. Because different applications have slightly different progress in adopting the changes made in the data and parser repo, I need to add 'child' and 'parent' as submodules directly to `grandparent` to gain better control of the source code, instead of letting `child` simply sit in `parent` and be `parent`'s submodule. And I also want `parent` has its own copy of `child` because the development of `parent` is standalone and not affected by any `grandparent`.

The file structure of three repos would be

```
grandparent
|-- src
|-- include
|-- submodules
    |-- parent
        |-- src
        |-- include
        |-- submodule
            |-- child (trying to make this one not being checked out here)
    |-- child (this one should be checked out)

parent
|-- src
|-- include
|-- submodules
    |-- child (this one should be checked out)

child
|-- audio
|-- video
|-- pics
|...
```

Is it possible to achieve what I described? Or what would be the best practice in such a scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the (updated) picture, I'd suggest avoiding recursive submodule mode and just manually (or scripted-ly?) doing any necessary `git submodule update` commands within the working tree of the `grandparent` repo.  That is:

```sh
git clone $url grandparent
cd grandparent
git submodule update --init
```

The `.gitmodules` (found in `grandparent/.gitmodules` after the `git clone`, and in `.gitmodules` after the `cd` command) would list the URL for `submodules/parent` and `submodules/child`.  The checkout done in the new `grandparent` directory created by `git clone`, when `git clone` reaches the last step of cloning (the checkout), will fill in both Git's index and your working tree, so that `submodules/parent` and `submodules/child` both have a hash ID recorded in the index.  Then the `git submodule update --init` will realize that it needs to run two `git clone` and `git checkout` commands to populate `submodules/parent` and `submodules/child`.

Since recursion is off (and the `git submodule update` is not told to turn it on either), the clone of `parent` leaves an un-cloned submodule: `submodules/parent/submodule/child` is just an empty directory at this point.  As long as nobody runs the command:

```
(cd submodules/parent && git submodule update --init)
```

or equivalent, that directory will continue to remain empty.